# Can't compile cpp-netlib example

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, codeblocks, cpp-netlib

I managed to install and run boost, I partialy also got to compile cpp-netlib's example code,
but I got stuck on this compile error:

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function 'ZN5boost7network3uri3uri5parseEv':

myCodeBlocksInstallPath\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1
\..\..\..\..\include\boost\network\uri\uri.hpp
(on line 211)

undefined reference to 
`boost::network::uri::detail::parse(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*,
std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>,
boost::network::uri::detail::uri_parts<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
std::string> >&)'
```

I am able to bypass this by removing the call and setting the variable myself to false:

```
//is_valid_ = detail::parse(first, last, uri_parts_);
is_valid_ = false;
```

But this doesn't really solve the problem. And I don't know what consequences it could have...

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error if I don't link against cpp-netlib: cpp-netlib is not a header-only library. The particular func you got a linker error for is in cpp-netlib-cpp-netlib-0.10.1/libs/network/src/uri.